# SQL how do I create 2 computed keys which create 1 composite key?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, hex, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I want to design a table which looks something like this:

`avaya nchar(6) NOT NULL,

startDate datetime NOT NULL,

endDate datetime NOT NULL,

sup_assigned nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,

myID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)`

But I want to table to stop any inserts/updates where the `avaya`, `startDate`, and `sup_assigned` are the same in any record OR the `avaya`, `endDate`, and `sup_assigned` are the same in any record.

How should I best go about doing this?

I thought about converting the set of 3 columns which include the `startDate` into hex and then add them creating `Key1` column, doing the same with the other 3 columns which include the `endDate` and have a `Key2` column. Then setting `Key1` and `Key2` as a composite key.

But I get this error:

- Unable to create table.
  A user-defined function name cannot be prefixed with a database name in this context.

How should I do this using MS SQL 2005?

Comment: I haven't tested this with your example, but is there some reason why a pair of unique indexes wouldn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better method is to use just a couple unique keys on the fields themselves, rather than de-normalizing the table by creating those derived fields:

```
UNIQUE KEY key_a (avaya, startDate, sup_assigned)
UNIQUE KEY key_b (avaya, endDate, sup_assigned)
```

That'll prevent any record from being inserted where either of those 3-way groupings are identical to some other record in the DB